# Где найти список всех событий javascript и как узнать когда фон блока загружен?

Tags: javascript, события

Где найти список всех событий javascript? искал на w3schools и w3 но списка с событиями не нашел.

Есть блок:

```
<div style="background: url('logo.png');"><div>
```

Как узнать когда картинка logo.png полностью загружена?

Comment: списка всех не бывает, т.к. можно и свои события делать. а  список мозилловских [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, есть *document.onload* — срабатывает после того, как всё-всё загружено. Если нужно узнать, загрузился ли в ваш блок бэкграунд, то нету таких событий вообще. Вы можете сами создать объект *new Image()*, загрузить его и вставить в блок — вот тогда и узнаете, что он загружен.

```
var i = new Image();
    i.src = 'logo.png';
    i.onload = function() {
        // тут мы знаем, что изображение подгрузилось
        // и что-нибудь делаем
        myDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + this.src + ')');
    };
```